# Apache HTTP Scoreboard - how it works?

Tags: apache

in a production environment we are using Apache HTTPD to serve requests from client to Tomcat instances. We have 3 nodes.

One day we got the following error:

AH00288: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers

more precisely it happens that one node shows those messages, after some minutes also the other node starts and finally also the third node.
Only the third node, before showing the scoreboard error, showed these two messages:

AH00287: server is within MinSpareThreads of MaxRequestWorkers, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
AH00286: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting

the scoreboard full message on the third node happened about an hour after these messages.
Now, I made a lot of reasearch on Google, forums, etc.. I've read all the posts about the mpm event bugs and so on.
I'm using mpm worker (so no event) and my settings are:

StartServers             3
        MinSpareThreads          25
        MaxSpareThreads          100
        ThreadLimit              64
        ThreadsPerChild          25
        MaxRequestWorkers        400
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   0

What I would like to understand is at least WHEN apache prints these messages.
What does it mean exactly that the scoreboard is full? I read a lot about graceful shutting down threads and stuff like that but, beside from a potential root cause, still don't understand what this mean.
I've understood that the scoreboard tracks the status of each tread (writing, reading, gracefully shutting down, ecc..) and that it has also empty spaces.
I expect that the total numeber of "spaces" is at least equals to the number of MaxRequestWorkers (otherwise I cannot se how Apache can keep track of the status of all threads).
So I do not understand in which circumstances it can fill up to the point I get this error.
Someone can explain me or provide some examples (or point me to a link) that let me understand how this scoreboard can get filled up so I can try to do some tests to reproduce the problem.
During the error it seems that the Apache were not accepting traffic and it is a big problem as you may guess.

The problem showed up for a couple of hours and then it disapperead when the traffic went down.
When the traffic went up again the next days, the problem fortunately hasn't show up anymore.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

From another user at [server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/516373/what-is-the-meaning-of-ah00485-scoreboard-is-full-not-at-maxrequestworkers) with [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/536062/505777)

### From Answer

We had the same problem on Apache 2.4.6. After monitoring the server and adjusting the setting for several hours it appears to us that Apache may have a bug. What appears to happen is that the server processes occasionally goes into the `G` state (Gracefully finishing) and restarts to accept new requests, that's normal. What is not normal is that for some reason this can take up to a few minutes to restart. If you only have a few server process running and they all go into the `G` state at the same time then your scoreboard fills up and you won't be able to server any more requests.

What we did was increase the number of servers so there is a less of a chance that they will all go into the `G` state at the same time. Also make sure you allocate at least 25 threads (`MaxRequestWorkers`) for each server process because that appears to be the default (i.e. if 5 `Servers` x 25 `ThreadsPerChild` = 125 `MaxRequestWorkers`). You can change `ThreadsPerChild` if you like, we left it at default. If you don't allocate enough threads the additional servers will not start. We left `MinSpareThreads` at the default value which is 25 and the default for `MaxSpareThreads` which is 75.  If you do modify these settings, the value for `MaxSpareThreads` must be greater than or equal to the sum of `MinSpareThreads` and `ThreadsPerChild`. Also `MaxRequestWorkers` must be equal to or less than the `ServerLimit`.

Here is what worked for us but it might not be the best configuration for you.

```
StartServers 3
MinSpareServers 5
MaxSpareServers 10
ServerLimit 250
MaxRequestWorkers 250
MaxConnectionsPerChild 1000
KeepAlive Off
```

Edit: This is a confirmed [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53555) in httpd's mpm_event module which might not be fixable through configuration.
The linked [bugtracker](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53555) entry has a presumed patch and more discussion about how to fix this until a new version of the event module is officially released.